# What's the main constituent part of botnet?

Tags: ddos, botnet

Is the botnet controlled broiler of servers or personal PCs?

We know the botnet can be controlled to DDoS attack, but what's the main constituent part of botnet?

I know the botnet's element maybe PC, Servers, and mobile devices, but what's the main constituent part of a botnet in general? I mean, which type element has the maximum count?

Comment: Have you've tried [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet#Overview) already? You should be able to find an answer to this there. To cite: *"A botnet is a logical collection of internet-connected devices such as computers, smartphones or IoT devices whose security has been breached and control ceded to a third party."*

Comment: also posting to multiple SE sites (ie also https://superuser.com/questions/1447259/is-the-botnet-controlled-broiler-of-servers-or-personal-pcs is uncool)

Comment: "which elements have the maximum count" Whatever applies to the individual botnet you're looking at. No "general" answer can be given, nor would that answer be of any relevance to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on the botnet. Some botnets are made up entirely of IoT devices, some are entirely made up of webservers, some are all PCs, some are a mix of everything.

There is no answer to your question without further defining what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:

> A botnet is a logical collection of internet-connected devices such as computers, smartphones or IoT devices whose security has been breached and control ceded to a third party.

the botnet can contain many types device who can connect to Internet.

but at the present stage, the mainstream method to create a botnet still is PCs.  from the botnet startup stage, the botnet nodes are main part of a botnet, now is it too.

but as the botnet grow, one PC provide's traffic is more less than one Server, so the Server's function is more than PC and phones.